# Why so many deal results?

Tags: mql5

I would like to print each closed trade's profit/loss to MetaTrader 5's "Expert" window...

```
void OnTrade()
  {
  HistorySelect(0,TimeCurrent());
  int trades_total = HistoryDealsTotal();
  ulong ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(trades_total-1);
  long deal_type=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_ENTRY);
  long deal_direction=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_ENTRY);

  if(deal_type == 1)
    {
     double profit=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_PROFIT);
     Print("Ticket ",ticket," Profit: ",profit," Direction: ",deal_direction);
    }
  } //END OnTrade()
```

...however what I get is not just one, but five (same) results:

[image]

What do I need to change in my code to obtain just one line?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You selected last deal in the series of closed deals

`ulong ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(trades_total-1);`
instead, you have to loop over all tickets from `trades_total-1` (last) to `0` (the very first).

```
for(int i=HistoryDealsTotal()-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
   ulong ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(i);
   //and rest of the code.
  }
```

also you probably need to mark start of the series - otherwise you will have 4,3,2,1,0,4,3... as every tick EA is called

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure? I want fewer lines, but the for-loop returns even more results per (old) line. Or am I doing something wrong? void OnTrade()
  {
  HistorySelect(0,TimeCurrent());
  
  ulong ticket;
  for(int i=HistoryDealsTotal()-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
  Alert("Loop #",i);
   ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(i);
   //and rest of the code.
  }

Comment: I do not know what you want... if you want EA to print the tickets each tick - that is what you tried to do and what you have. if you want ea to do this check only once per bar - add isNewBar() check, if you want to it only once - use global variable or static variable. Seems you told you want to see each closed deal - so loop over all closed deals as i showed

Comment: My code does what I want in principle (gets the last order close [HistoryDealsTotal()-1] profit/loss), just too many times for whatever reason. Maybe OnTrade() is fired more than once when an order is closed (by TP or SL in this case) and I need to figure out how they differ so that I can filter out all but one...

Comment: OnTrade() is called four times on each transaction done in mql5, as far as i remember. so need to filter the event (do not remember them all, last seems to be position modification). Try to compare `OrdersTotal()` with `saved_value`, if less then probably deal is closed, and then update `ulong saved_value=OrdersTotal()`

Comment: Yes, how we did last time with the order number :) Thanks, I already posted an according answer, maybe you want to upvote since this one we kind of did together? ;-)

Comment: You are right with four times, by the way: 1. Creating order to open by market.
2. Deal execution.
3. Passing complete order to history.
4. Position Opening. https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/40

Comment: yes, I think the article is exactly what you need. I would upvote if you add article link

Comment: It's www.mql5.com/en/articles/40 ;-) Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166002/discussion-between-daniel-kniaz-and-bromelio).

Answer (score 0):

I still couldn't figure out how those 5 lines in my screenshot above differ (if somebody knows please comment), but that's not necessary anyway since it's not only possible to filter by differences, but also by *common* properties:

```
uint lastDealsTotal; //global variable
[...]
void OnTrade()
{
   uint dealsTotal = HistoryDealsTotal();
   [...]
   if(dealsTotal != lastDealsTotal)
   {
     Print([...]);
   }
   [...]
   lastDealsTotal = dealsTotal;
 } //END OnTrade()
```